# Configure Travis to skip queued builds except the last one?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have configured Travis to test my GitHub project. Is it possible to configure Travis to test only the latest push (i.e. build)?

For example: I push `fixA` commits that I know that breaks some tests, and then right after, I push `fixB` commits that fixes everything. Both push requests will trigger Travis to test the build and two builds will be queued.

Since neither build is started at the moment of queuening, it is perfectly acceptable for me to skip testing of all queued builds (the first one) except the last one (the second one in this example). This would save some CPU cycles and time for Travis server and I would get response sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out in [Travis documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/how-to-skip-a-build/):

> Sometimes all you are changing is the README, some documentation or other things which have no effect on the tests. In this case, you may not want a build to be created for that commit. To do this, all you need to do is to add [ci skip] somewhere in the commit message.

Cool.